# sakila ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 46412: Access denied for user 'ted'@'localhost' to database 'sakila'

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1044

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I am deploying the sakila database for learning mysql and have done the following:

1. Downloaded the file "sakila-db.tar.gz from https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/
   to the directory "/tmp" with no problem
2. `$ cd /tmp`
3. $ gzip -cd sakila-db.tar.gz | tar xvf - 
    Files sakila-data.sql, sakila-schema.sql and sakila.mwb were extracted to diredctory "sakila-db"
4. `$ cd sakila-db`
5. `$ mysql -u root -p < sakila-schema.sql` 
   (command executed successfully)
6. `$ mysql -u root -p`
    (to grant privileges to user for the sakila database)
7. mysql> GRANT CREATE, DROP, ALTER, INSERT, UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE,
   INDEX, CREATE VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, EXECUTE,
   TRIGGER, INDEX ON sakila.* TO 'jump'@'localhost';

   (command executed successfully)
8. `mysql> GRANT SUPER, RELOAD, FILE ON *.* TO 'ted'@'localhost';`
   (granting these global commands to user ted - command executed OK)
9. mysql> exit
10. Trying to populate the sakila tables with data from `sakila-data.sql`

    $ mysql -u ted -p < sakila-data.sql

Enter password:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000) at line 46412: Access denied for user 'ted'@'localhost' to database 'sakila'
```

This is my problem, can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: What clue do you have for granting privileges to the user in the correct schema?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem by issuing the following commands:
Connecting to mysql: $ mysql -u root -p;
Issuing a global grant on the database: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'ted'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION; 
Then exiting mysql;
Issuing the command: $ mysql -u ted -p mysql> use mysql; but ... ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user '' @ 'localhost' to database 'mysql'.